# Why do some legendaries have stats beyond their definitions?

Tags: diablo-iii

Here's an example.

First, take a look at the official DB entry for [Andariel's Visage](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/andariels-visage). Note that only one random magic property should appear on the item, in addition to one of strength, dexterity and intelligence between 112 and 129.

Well I just found an Andariel's Visage which has 171 strength — well beyond the maximum according to the official D3 database. It also has the random stat of 26 vitality, so it can't be an overlapping strength affix (is that even possible?).

[image: The proof]

What's going on? I suppose the database definition could be incorrect, but I swear I've seen this happen before.

Comment: looks like there is a `magic property` that gave +42 str and +26 vita. I do believe that such a property exists

Comment: Of course, it totally went past me that affixes can give more than one stat. That explains everything. Care to submit an actual answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a magic property that gave you `+42 strength` and `+26 vitality`.

Hope it helps ;)

**EDIT**

As [Alok](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/25150/alok) wrote in the comment it is most probably the `Dauntless` affix.

Link: http://www.diablofans.com/topic/41045-spoiler-diablo-iii-item-affixes/

Comment: Thanks! Having looked at the affixes, it's not necessarily +42 strength (it could be that the base strength roll was lower) but that's sort of besides the point.

Comment: Possibly the `Dauntless` affix (http://www.diablofans.com/topic/41045-spoiler-diablo-iii-item-affixes/)