# How does stats roll works on item in diablo 3

Tags: diablo-iii

my question is quite simple :

When crafting bracers, amulets, pauldrons or gauntlets for a given stat (int,str,dex or vitality) : the roll of the given stat is for example 201-230 for pauldron. How come you can roll 300+ on the stat then ?

Same question for some legendaries like The dead man's legacy  (http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/dead-mans-legacy) which can roll 170-200 dex and 170-200 vita, however you can roll 300+ dex and 300+ vita.

How does it work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because there are different affixes. For example: `Dead Man's Legacy` indeed gives you `+170–200 Dexterity` and `+170–200 Vitality`, but it also gives you `+1 Random Magic Properties`. And that random property could have been `Valiant` for example, which gives the item `+45-150 Dexterity` and `+45-150 Vitality`. So a perfect roll of these stats would give you a `Dead Man's Legacy` with `350 Dexterity` and `350 Vitality`.

You can find the list of item affixes here: http://www.diablofans.com/topic/41045-spoiler-diablo-iii-item-affixes/

P.S. The very similar question has been asked and answered previously. Here is the link to the answer: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/73345/25490

Comment: Okay, i thougt "1 random magic property" refers only to +x in 1 stat, not 2, that explains a lot, thanks